# Error in executing soap request using Curl command(linux)

Tags: curl, soap

i have curl command to POST a soap request to web service. I have a file (query.xml) which has all the soap message attached to it I just don't seem to be able to properly post it.

curl command

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: text/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8" -H "SOAPAction:" -d @query.xml http://10.130.9.79:7782/services/CBSInterfaceBusinessMgrService
```

query.xml

```
<q2:QueryBasicInfoRequestMsg
    xmlns:q0="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbs/businessmgr"
    xmlns:q1="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/common"
    xmlns:q2="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbs/businessmgrmsg">
    <parameter name="enableREST">true</parameter>
    <RequestHeader>
            <q1:CommandId>QueryBasicInfo
            </q1:CommandId>
            <q1:Version>1
            </q1:Version>
            <q1:TransactionId/>
                    <q1:SequenceId>1
                    </q1:SequenceId>
                    <q1:RequestType>Event
                    </q1:RequestType>
                    <q1:SerialNo>03020000003
                    </q1:SerialNo>
    </RequestHeader><QueryBasicInfoRequest>q0:SubscriberNo>9150000014</q0:SubscriberNo> <q0:QueryType>3</q0:QueryType> </QueryBasicInfoRequest</q2:QueryBasicInfoRequestMsg>
```

error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header> <wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/none
```

urn:uuid:AAC81E84BC63EF7AA81443502795856131 http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault  faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '-' (code 45) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,22]

Please throw some light how to get this moving & since i am new in this forum so tried my level best for tags but had some issues in above(error)

Answer (score 0):

The curl commandline is perfect. You have problem with your soap envelope. I can see that you are not closing the tag properly. Missing `>` there

```
</QueryBasicInfoRequest</q2:QueryBasicInfoRequestMsg>
                       ^ missing '>' character here
```

Comment: I have edited the xml file but still getting the following error  "Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]"

Answer (score 0):

Your example XML is incorrect, its not parsable. Use below one, that I have corrected manually.
I'm not sure your web service really a SOAP service, because I don't find SOAPEnvelope into your request at all. Anyways, I think below should work for you.

```
<q2:QueryBasicInfoRequestMsg
xmlns:q0="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbs/businessmgr"
xmlns:q1="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/common"
xmlns:q2="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbs/businessmgrmsg">
<parameter name="enableREST">true</parameter>
<RequestHeader>
    <q1:CommandId>QueryBasicInfo
    </q1:CommandId>
    <q1:Version>1
    </q1:Version>
    <q1:TransactionId/>
    <q1:SequenceId>1
    </q1:SequenceId>
    <q1:RequestType>Event
    </q1:RequestType>
    <q1:SerialNo>03020000003
    </q1:SerialNo>
</RequestHeader>
<QueryBasicInfoRequest><q0:SubscriberNo>9150000014</q0:SubscriberNo>
<q0:QueryType>3</q0:QueryType>
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, let me know, I should be able help you create SOAPEnvelope and add XMLs inside it?